# Automated tests in iOS with RobotFramework

Tags: ios, automated-tests, robotframework, appium-ios

I'm working in a project of develop a responsive webapp and I'm in charge of creating automated tests in order to test everything in 3 different places, Desktop web, Android web and iOS web with RobotFramework and Appium Library

Desktop and Android it's not the first time I've done it so I quickly configured everything, on the other hand I never tested or even develop anything for iOS (not even used an iPhone irl) and I know from a past experience that XCode has required to send data to the phone, in a similar way to adb for Android.

The real question that my research was not able to respond is: Is a MacOS environment running XCode needed in order to run regression tests? Or is it possible in someway just use Windows, Robot and a physical phone/emulator to run regression tests?

In the case that a MacOS is required do I need Apple Developer ID? (I remember a few years back that it was required for any iOS related development).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're using MacOS and running with Real Device iOS you will require to have Developer Account to provision profile WebDriverAgent or Otherwise you need to have certificate from your developer to install on your Mac. [Create Your Apple Dev Account](https://appleid.apple.com/account?appId=632&returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fenroll%2F#!&page=create). And if you want try with Windows you can try with [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I'm currently using Windows and CentOS. the ID is not a big deal since now they are free. My biggest doubt was actually if a MacOS environment was needed in order to test on iPhones

Comment: Sure , the most important automation iOS is need Xcode that why we need Mac OS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a MacOS to test with Appium/AppiumLibrary and Robot Framework.

You don't need an Apple Developer ID to test on iOS (only need it when publishing apps to Apple Store).

Comment: Testing on iOS is need provisioning profile to real device and the reason is need Apple Dev.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Helio. I confirmed a Mac Mini for me and the team to start working on it.